# Changing a scope value from a directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a validation message that is set to hidden with ng-show when the page loads. The user can then click to delete an entry and they will be presented with a successful deletion confirmation message by setting that ng-show value to false.

I now want to set that validation message box back to hidden when the user clicks the close 'x' button.

This has to be as dynamic as possible as various different validation messages can be shown for adding a new entry, editing and entry, deleting one etc etc. So I wanted to keep this as DRY as possible and JQuery get the 'x' and change that $scope value back to false.

Here's the code:

To initialise the module.

```
var app = angular.module('myGUI', []);
```

To set the controller.

```
angular.module('myGUI').controller('DisplayController', function($scope){
    $scope.deleteModal = false;
    $scope.successAdded = false;
});
```

The directive.

```
app.directive ('closeMessage', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        transclude: true,
        link: function (scope) {
            $('.close-alert').on('click', function() {
                var messageToClose = $(this).parent().attr('ng-show');
                scope[messageToClose] = false;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And the HTML.

```
<div class="alert-added alert-success  col-xs-12" ng-show="successAdded">
    <h2>Success!</h2>
    <i class="fa fa-check-circle close-message"></i> You have successfully added an entry <i class="fa fa-times close-alert"></i>
</div>
```

I hope that makes sense. Would really appreciate any help you all may be able to provide.

Many thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do below `ng-click="successAdded = false"` on the `<i>` element

```
<div class="alert-added alert-success  col-xs-12" ng-show="successAdded">
    <h2>Success!</h2>
    <i class="fa fa-check-circle close-message"></i> You have successfully added an entry <i class="fa fa-times close-alert" ng-click="successAdded = false"></i>
</div>
```

you can use the [alert directives](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/alert) from angular-ui which provides this functionality in-built.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was as simple as that! You sir, get an up-vote. Thank you very much!

Comment: please get out of jquery mindset.. i would advice you to remove jquery entierly from your angular app.. that would be best way to learn angular